# fastapi: использовать middleware для формирования результата, в котором изначальный результат включен в качестве элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, middleware

есть такой код:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    # выполнить запрос
    results = await call_next(request)

    return JSONResponse(content={
        'response': results 
    })

  
@app.post("/test/")
async def test_func():
    results = {
        'test': 10
    }

    return results
```

но выдаются ошибки

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type 
_StreamingResponse is not JSON serializable
```

как корректно передать results как элемент выходного словаря

нужен ли вообще JSONResponse?

думал, что можно сделать просто:

```
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    # выполнить запрос
    results = await call_next(request)

    return {
        'response': results 
    }
```

но нет

Comment: попробуй вот так, мне помогло https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882419/fastapi-how-to-get-the-response-body-in-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Если целью является получить результат который работы какого-либо эндпоинта, то вот код который реализует это:

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    response_body = [chunk async for chunk in response.body_iterator]
    response.body_iterator = iterate_in_threadpool(iter(response_body))
    x = response_body[0].decode() # в переменной x будет ответ
    return response
```

Если целью является всегда оборачивать ответ в JSON, как это сделали вы в своем примере кода. То вот пример кода:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    response_body = [chunk async for chunk in response.body_iterator]
    response.body_iterator = iterate_in_threadpool(iter(response_body))
    x = response_body[0].decode()
    return JSONResponse(content={
        'response': x
    })
```